# Why are the extra buttons on my Logitech mouse no longer working under 20.04?

Tags: xorg, mouse, 20.04, xev

I've got a Logitech G700s mouse. Using the extra buttons under Eon worked just fine. Now I've updated to Focal and suddenly all the extra buttons aren't working. Button 1 and 2 and the scroll wheel are working without issue.

```
xinput list            
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G700s                            id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 046a:0023                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

xinput list-props  8     
Device 'Logitech G700s':

Device 'Logitech G700s':
    Device Enabled (154):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (156): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (291):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (292):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (293):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (294):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (295):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (296): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (297): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (298):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (299):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (300): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (301): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (302):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (303):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (304):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (305): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (306): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (276): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (277):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (278):    0, 0
    Device Node (279):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (280):    1133, 4138
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (307):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (308):   1
```

Button 1 and 2 + the wheel showed up under `xev`, but all the other extra buttons did not generate any output. I also ran `sudo evtest /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if01-event-mouse` and got the same results as with `xev`. Button 1, 2 and mousewheel are working fine. Everything else doesn't show up.

How do I get the extra buttons to work again?

Comment: To bring one more little stone in the issue, I also pursued a bit of investigations and I discoverd that the problem occurs when the radio connection is used. If I connect the mouse with the USB wire directly, it works fine. I hope this can help understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tinkering and discovered that the `hid_logitech_dj` module is causing this issue. I disabled the module via adding `hid_logitech_dj` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and `install hid_logitech_dj /bin/false` to a new `/etc/modprobe.d/logitech-mouse.conf` file. Then I rebooted my system and everything works fine again!